# Function never get called without @inlineCallback

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

I was trying to test twisted callback functions and see the below code is working. However, when I remove `@inlineCallback` in the code, I don't see "Hello" message printed and it seems never executed.

If I use the `hello` function without for loop inside, then it prints "Hello" without `@inlineCallback` decorator. How this is possible?

If `yield` statement doesn't exist, it executes normally; however, if `yield` statement exists in the function, then it executes only when decorated with `@inlineCallback`.

How this is possible??

```
from autobahn.twisted.component import run
from autobahn.twisted.util import sleep

@inlineCallback
def hello():
    print "Hello"
    for i in range(0, 3):
        print "Hello", i
        yield sleep(1)

reactor.callLater(1, hello)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Do you know how Python generators work?  It sounds like you should read up on that.

Comment: I just understood how generator works. If a function has `yield` statement, python considers the function as a generator not a normal function.

Comment: Do you know what `f()` does if `f` is a generator function (specifically compared to the case where `f` is a normal function)?